# cell selection of UICollectionView does not work in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have written sample code here -  when i tap button "Select" it should select all the cells of UICollectionView. But is does not work and no error is reported. Below is code

// collectionView is name of UICollectionView

```
let collectonViewCount = collectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(0);

        for i in 0...collectonViewCount {

            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)
            collectionView.selectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .None)

        }
```

I'm not sure what could be wrong in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

cybergeeeek,

you can try

```
for i in 0...collectonViewCount {
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)
collectionView.delegate?.collectionView!(collectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}
```

This answer ofcourse assumes that you have set the collectionView delegate and have implemented `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` this will select the collectionView cell and will trigger didSelectItemAtIndexPath :)

Comment: did not work... it is crashing.. inside didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Comment: @cybergeeeek : May I know the crash please ??? I never had any issue with this piece of code infact I have used it in one of the accepted answwer as well (not the same question though ) :)

Comment: error is "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: @cybergeeeek : have you set collectionView.delegate = self ???? I have clearly stated in my answer will work only if you have delegate assigned :)

Comment: @cybergeeeek : Can you please post modified your code I have a working code with me and its working absolutely fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113117/discussion-between-cybergeeeek-and-sandeep-bhandari).